# Xpages onClick execution sequence

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, hcl

I want to create a button that executes different actions/scripts in a particular sequence.
First, I want to save the current document (server side action). After saving the document, a partial refresh is performed. Then a client side script should be carried out. When finishing this script, a new page is opened.

My current button:

```
<xp:button id="saveButton" value="Save">
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(document1.isEditable()){
           return true;
          }
          else{ 
           return false
          }
    }]]></xp:this.rendered>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="true" refreshId="saveButton">

                        <xp:this.action>

                            <xp:actionGroup>
                                <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>

                                <xp:openPage name="/viewer.xsp"
                                    target="openDocument">
                                </xp:openPage>
                            </xp:actionGroup>
                        </xp:this.action>



                        <xp:this.script>
                            <xp:executeClientScript>
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                                    someScript();
                                ]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeClientScript>
                        </xp:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
```

Currently, this button first executes all server side events and then the client script. Is there a solution to arrange the order of execution, so that I can execute server->client->server?

**EDITED:**

The functionality I want, splitted in three buttons:

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="execute1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="execute2">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:saveDocument var="document1"></xp:saveDocument>
</xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>


<xp:button value="Label" id="execute2"><xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script>
        <xp:executeClientScript>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            someScript();
        }});]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:executeClientScript>
</xp:this.script></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>


<xp:button value="Label" id="execute3"><xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:openPage name="/viewer.xsp" target="openDocument"></xp:openPage>
</xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

So I would click execute1 => execute 2 => execute 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from view.postScript, as Paul suggests, you can add client-side JavaScript to onComplete for the event. This will run after the event is finished. I'm not certain if there is a big difference behind the scenes in regards to view.postScript vs onComplete.

You could create a hidden button (style="display: none;") that runs the second server side code. and trigger the click event for that after the first server event is complete.

Answer (score 6):

The order of operation is:

- run client-side (JavaScript) code defined in the action on the browser
- submit the page to the server
- JSF lifecycle kicks in and, after processing the browser content, server-side code runs
- XPage is recalculated
- HTML is passed back to the browser to be rendered

Adding JavaScript into the  tag of the button won't achieve what you need, because it can't.

What you're looking for is to pass JavaScript back to the page to be run after everything else has happened. This is what `view.postScript(String)` will do for you - it literally posts script to run after (post) the HTML has been returned to the browser. Because this runs from the `view` object, this is server-side code, and passes a String that will be parsed by the browser as JavaScript.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. postScript is not solving my problem: If I use postScript, I have to use Full Update before executing my client script. But I want to save my document, then execute a client script and after that open a new page / update my page. The reason for this is that I need some values from my client for this script. When I update the page these values will be lost. I was wondering if I could call "Save document" from a client-side script. So far I did this by adding three independent buttons. Is there a "cleaner" solution where I only use one button?